# How to add resizing slider to rectangle shape in java?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, shapes, jslider

Here is my rectangle shape code:

```
 if(rect){
    gphcs.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    if(orangeshp)
        gphcs.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    if(greenshp)
        gphcs.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    gphcs.fillRect(20,35,100,30);
}
```

I want to to add a resizing slider in order to change size of the rectangle.

Here is a sample pic of the slider I want to add:

[image]

I just need any simple code to create this slider.

Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 1):

```
JSlider size = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 250, 100);
```

Comment: BTW - if that is not the answer, I suggest you edit the question (to make it more specific).

Answer (score 1):

```
JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 250, 100);
slider.addChangeListener(this);


public void stateChanged (ChangeEvent event){
 JSlider slider = (JSlider)event.getSource();
 int value = slider.getValue();
 //manipulate the value in the proption you wants to increase your coordinate of rectangle
 //change the size of rectangle here     
}
```